# Angular ngIf removes input checked value

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Take the following `ngIf` conditional:

**ms-aside.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="showFilters">
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" checked="" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  ...
</div>
```

Whenever the `showFilters` variable is changed to a *falsy* value, my input *checked* value states are lost. As in, when I re-assign the `showFilters` variable to a truthy value, the checked values are reset to none.

Can anyone shed some light on why that is, and how I can work around this issue?

Comment: Daniel Hilgarth has the right answer, but to add to that; you should  use two-way-binding to keep the state of your checkboxes.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is actually pretty simple: The children of an element with `*ngIf === false` are removed from the DOM.

So, whenever you change `showFilters` to `false`, the inputs are removed. And when you change it to `true`, new instances are then added to the DOM.

To fix this, you will have to control them, i.e. store the value of the checked state in your component and bind it to the inputs.

Answer (score 3):

When you use *ngIf, the following element is removed from the DOM if the condition is false. If you want to retain the states [hidden] might work for you as it just hides the element but does not remove the element from DOM.

Comment: @Silvermind: That was understood but thanks for adding it! :)